# Vaadin: parameter value not found after routing

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm currently building a Vaadin application and I'm having problems with routing.

I have a grid with a list of entities (**Team**) and i need to be able to edit a single element.
While editing the element i should be able to edit a list of **Players** that belong to the **Team**.

This is how it should work:

1. Click on the edit button
2. Open a new view (edit view)
3. Click on the add player button
4. Open a dialog and search for player
5. Select player and click Add player button

Whenever I'm trying to add the player, i get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.focs.auctionfriend.data.entities.Squadra.getListaGiocatoriAcquistati()" because "this.squadra" is null at com.focs.auctionfriend.views.squadre.EditSquadraView.lambda$openAcquistaGiocatoreDialog$f9bc1709$1(EditSquadraView.java:123)
```

EditSquadraView.java:123 takes here:

```
private void openAcquistaGiocatoreDialog() {
    Button acquistaButton = new Button("Acquista", event -> {
        Giocatore giocatoreSelezionato = giocatoriDialogGrid.asSingleSelect().getValue();

        if (giocatoreSelezionato != null) {
            // this is line 123:
            squadra.getListaGiocatoriAcquistati().add(giocatoreSelezionato);
            squadraService.saveSquadra(squadra);

            // Chiudi il dialog dopo l'acquisto
            dialog.close();
          giocatoriGrid.setItems(squadra.getListaGiocatoriAcquistati());
        }
    });

    content.add(acquistaButton);
}
```

Now, from what I learned from debugging the code, I can tell that the parameter that I'm trying to pass from a view (TeamsView) to the other (EditTeamView) is null in the method:

```
@Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, @OptionalParameter String parameter) {
        if (parameter != null) {
            Long squadraId = Long.parseLong(parameter);
            Optional<Squadra> optionalSquadra = squadraService.getSquadraById(squadraId);

            if (optionalSquadra.isPresent()) {
                this.squadra = optionalSquadra.get();
                giocatoriGrid.setItems(this.squadra.getListaGiocatoriAcquistati());

            }
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing that the method setParameter is invoked right after the click on the edit button. Here is the implementation:

```
grid.addComponentColumn(squadra -> {
            Button editButton = new Button("Modifica");
            editButton.addClickListener(e -> {
                UI.getCurrent().navigate("modifica-squadra/" + squadra.getId());
            });
            return editButton;
        }).setHeader("");
```

I can't get around this error, I've tried with different approaches but I'm sure I'm missing something and the Vaading documentation isn't enough in this case.

Comment: Please correlate the exception with your code. There is no need "for guessing" - the stacktrace will tell you exactly where it is happening.

Comment: Given, that the error is inside a click listener, the most likely
explanation is, that you never have set `squadra` and what you think
that `squadra` is there, is actually something else.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. The thing is, I'm trying to pass `squadra `as a parameter from the read view to the edit view. From the vaadin documentation i can see that i can navigate like so `UI.getCurrent().navigate("modifica-squadra/" + squadra.getId());` and `squadra.getId` is valid.

Comment: Create
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(e.g. download a starter and build the minimum of what you are after
with that). It will help you to understand the problem.  And in case you
will not find the missing assignment there, you can add the code here
instead and we don't have to guess your way through hundreds of lines of
code.